# CAN NOT RETURN THE VALUE IN INT FUNCTION C++

Tags: c++, return-value

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
 

int nearestFibonacci(int num)
{
    
    if (num == 0) {
        cout << 0;
        return;
    }

    int first = 0, second = 1;
    int third = first + second;

    while (third <= num) {
        first = second;
        second = third;
        third = first + second;
    }
    int ans = (abs(third - num)
               >= abs(second - num))
                  ? second
                  : third;
    
    return ans;
}
 
int main()
{   int a = 0;
    int N = 20;
    a = nearestFibonacci(N);
    cout << a;
 
    return 0;
}
```

I have a code like this, however I got this error:

**test.cpp: In function 'int nearestFibonacci(int)':**

**test.cpp:10:9: error: return-statement with no value, in function returning 'int' [-fpermissive]
return;
^~~~~~**

I can not return the value **ans**. Can someone  explain and guide me how to return value in the right way.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Your problem is the return with no value when `num == 0` at the top of your function.

Comment: The error message includes the line of code. It's talking about the `return;` line, not `return ans;`.

Comment: `test.cpp:10:9` points at 10th line, 9th character, where you have just "return". The output there is superfluos. Aslo Fibonacci's closest number to 0 is 1. :P

Comment: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 2):

The function `int nearestFibonacci(int num)` is expecting an `int` value when returning. When you type `return;` your returning without a value. A simple fix would be to just `return 0;` in the `num == 0` case. Here is the working code.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
 

int nearestFibonacci(int num)
{
    
    if (num == 0) {
        return 0; // Changed it to return 0 when num == 0
    }

    int first = 0, second = 1;
    int third = first + second;

    while (third <= num) {
        first = second;
        second = third;
        third = first + second;
    }
    int ans = (abs(third - num)
               >= abs(second - num))
                  ? second
                  : third;
    
    return ans;
}
 
int main()
{   int a = 0;
    int N = 20;
    a = nearestFibonacci(N);
    cout << a;
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @Evg I 100% agree with your comment. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am really appreciate your guiding. Thank you so much. Hope many happy return to you

Comment: @LộcNguyễnThế Glad, I could help. If this answer is helpful. I would appreciate it if you could mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return an integer value in all paths inside your function `nearestFibonacci()` because this function is expected to always return an integer.

Your original code does not return an integer for the case `num == 0`  inside the first `if` statement at the top of that function.

To fix the error, you simply need to return 0 for the case `num == 0`  as shown in the code below

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
 

int nearestFibonacci(int num)
{
    
    if (num == 0) {
        return 0;    // You should return 0 here.
    }

    int first = 0, second = 1;
    int third = first + second;

    while (third <= num) {
        first = second;
        second = third;
        third = first + second;
    }
    int ans = (abs(third - num)
               >= abs(second - num))
                  ? second
                  : third;
    
    return ans;
}
 
int main()
{   int a = 0;
    int N = 20;
    a = nearestFibonacci(N);
    std::cout << a;
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Good point. I do not use those in my own code. I only re-use them from the OP's code for a quick answer to his question. :-)

Comment: But I guess nothing stops you from removing it instead of proliferating that bad practice, right? :)

Comment: thank you so much. Now I got the problem. Because I am a new programing learner so I usually trend to get stupid errors. But I will try my best to improve. Thank you very much

Comment: @Evg, How do the header files look now ?

Comment: Much better. However, this code won't compile due to missing `std::` qualification.

Comment: @Evg, Oh, I had that ```std::cout<<``` in my code, but I forgot to copy that to the answer. It compiles now.